# cancel react .hover function after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, mouseover

I am trying to cancel (`.off`) the .hover on function, can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("button").hover(function(){
       $("h1").hide();
    },
    function(){
       $("h1").show()}
    );

    $("button").click( function(){
        alert("turning off hover")
        $("button").off( "hover" )
    } );
});
```

I do get the alert, but the .hover is still active..

Comment: Did you mean `jquery` instead of `react` in your title and tags ? Your code has nothing related to react.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mouseenter` and `mouseout` event instead

```js
$( "#yourButton" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $("#yourH1").hide();
});
$( "#yourButton" ).mouseout(function() {
  $("#yourH1").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="yourButton">Hover me</button>

<h1 id="yourH1"> Hey </button>
```